# How does case insensitive sort work in Swift or other languages?

Tags: swift, sorting

So, I am fetching some data from CoreData and I am using `NSSortDescriptor` to sort it in ascending order (I've tried other methods too). What happens is that the lowercase string with same text comes first. As per my understanding, in ASCII, uppercase strings come first ('A' starting at 65) and then lowercase strings ('a' starting at 97) and if we consider this, uppercase strings should come first when sorting in ascending order.

```
let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true, selector: #selector(NSString.caseInsensitiveCompare(_:)))

let entities = CoreDataManager.getData(entityName: "Entity", predicate: nil, sortDescriptor: sortDescriptor) as? [Entity]
```

In my CoreDataManager class, I have the following methods.

```
class CoreDataManager: NSObject {

    static func getManagedObject() -> NSManagedObjectContext {
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        return appDelegate.managedObjectContext
    }
    
    static func getData(entityName: String, predicate: NSPredicate? = nil, sortDescriptor: NSSortDescriptor? = nil) -> [NSManagedObject] {
        var resultsManagedObject: [NSManagedObject] = []
        do {
            let managedObject = getManagedObject()
            let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: entityName)
            
            if let descriptor = sortDescriptor {
                request.sortDescriptors = [descriptor]
            }
            
            if predicate != nil {
                request.predicate = predicate
            }
            
            let results = try managedObject.fetch(request)
            resultsManagedObject = results as! [NSManagedObject]
        } catch {
            print("There was an error retrieving data")
        }
        return resultsManagedObject
    }
}
```

I've also tried sorting using `sorted` method of arrays but that was also giving the same output as using `NSSortDescriptor`.

```
let arr = ["bamboo", "document", "BAMBOO", "DOCUMENT"]

print(arr.sorted { $0.lowercased() < $1.lowercased() }) // Output ~> ["bamboo", "BAMBOO", "document", "DOCUMENT"]
```

Why is sorting working like this? Is it the same in other languages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not sorting lowercase first. It's comparing uppercase and lowercase as *equal*. But obviously, in an array, *something* has to come first. If a sorting algorithm is "stable", then if two elements compare equal, the one that appears first in the input will also appear first in the output. If the algorithm is "unstable" they might come out in any random order. It looks like you're getting a stable sort (or just getting lucky); since your example input has lowercase values before their corresponding uppercase values, the output does too.

Comment: Oh alright. So that would mean for me to get my intended behaviour, all I have to do is sort it initially using regular sorting method which is case sensitive, which gives an array where lowercased strings comes on the bottom and then sort again case insensitively, which would give me the desired result where uppercase strings come on top. And thanks for clarifying about case insensitivity which would mean both strings are considered same.. For some reason that was going over my head